# AWS Amplify withAuthenticator not in the center

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am making a portfolio-building project, and am using AWS Amplify with Reactjs.  I am wrapping my app component in withAuthenticator() for sign in, but the problem is the authentication logic is displaying in the upper right corner of the screen when I first access the website.  Is there any way to bring it to the center? Thanks!